# Why does the HTML5 continuous listening sample have to ask for mic permission every time?

Tags: html, speech-recognition, html5-audio, microphone

Why does the speech reco code on this page fall under the constraint of having to ask the user to allow permission every reco session on a non-HTTPS URL:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/tag/voice

when the plain jane push-to-talk HTML5 speech input button does not as you can see on this page:

http://www.web2voice.com/chrome-speech-input.html

The first sample is the HTML5 rocks sample and does continuous speech recognition.  As that page says:

"Pages hosted on HTTPS do not need to ask repeatedly for permission, whereas *HTTP hosted pages do*."

But I am trying to figure out why HTML5 speech reco audio input behaves different in push-to-talk mode.  The second example is my HTML5 speech reco demo page that uses the plain jane web x-webkit-speech button.  My sample, that uses the push-to-talk x-webkit-speech button, *only has to ask for permission once* and from that point on mic usage is allowed, even between completely new browser sessions.  What is it about the HTML5 continuous listening sample that puts it in a far more restrictive category?